# Pollard Rho can't find factor

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger, factorization

So I am attempting to create a Pollard's Rho Factoring Algorithm in Java using the BigInteger class to support very large integers. The code mostly works but cannot find a factor for 4 or 8 (which should be 2). Currently I have capped it to cycle through the algorithm 10,000,000 times and still it can't find 2 as a factor. `a` is generated randomly (limited between 0 and 1000). Is this just a flaw in the Pollard Rho Algorithm or is there a mistake somewhere in the implementation?

The `n` being passed is 4

The initial `a` is calculated as a random the same way in the below code, between 0 and 1000

The `sqrt(n)` method returns the floor of the square root of n (in this case `sqrt(sqrt(4)) = 1`

I printed `count` at the end to make sure it was actually iterating how many times it was supposed to.

```
private static BigInteger PollardRho (BigInteger a, BigInteger n) {

    BigInteger gcd = BigInteger.ZERO;

    BigInteger Tort = a;

    BigInteger Hare = a;

    BigInteger count = BigInteger.ZERO;

    BigInteger iterationLim = (sqrt(sqrt(n))).multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(10000000));

    while (count.compareTo(iterationLim)!=0)
    //makes sure that the algorithm does not surpass (4th root of n)*10000000 iterations.
    {

    Tort = ((Tort.pow(2)).add(BigInteger.ONE)).mod(n);

    //System.out.println("Tort: "+Tort);

    Hare = (((Hare.pow(2)).add(BigInteger.ONE).pow(2)).add(BigInteger.ONE)).mod(n);

    //System.out.println("Hare: "+Hare);

    gcd = (Tort.subtract(Hare)).gcd(n);

    //System.out.println("gcd: "+gcd);

    if (gcd.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) != 0 && gcd.compareTo(n) != 0)
    {
    //  System.out.println("took if, gcd = "+gcd);

        return gcd;
    }

    if (gcd.compareTo(n) == 0)
    {
        a = (BigInteger.valueOf((long) (1000*Math.random())));
        Tort = a;
        Hare = a;
    }

    count = count.add(BigInteger.ONE);

    }

    System.out.println(count);
    return n;


}
```

Comment: Have you single-stepped your code, examining each intermediate result and verifying that it's doing what you think it should?

Comment: I have, it will continually find a gcd equal to n, calculate a new a, try again, and cycle until it hits the iteration limit.

Comment: Seems like if you examined each intermediate result (i.e. the result at every line, not just at the end of the iteration), then you could determine which line isn't working the way you think it should. If, that is, you understand what your code is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 4):

Pollard's Rho method usually can only split numbers composed of *different* primes. It fails most of the time for numbers that are prime powers. 4 and 8 are powers of a single prime 2 and therefore unlikely to be split by this method.

The method works by iterating a random function f(x) mod n, in this case f(x) = x^2+1 is used, but other functions work as well. The trick is that f(x) mod p where p is a prime factor of n enters a cycle after a different number of iterations for different primes. So f(x) mod p1 may already be in a cycle, f(x) mod p2 not yet. The gcd calculation is then able to find the factor p1.

It is btw. very easy to check if a number is a proper power of an integer. Just calculate the 2nd, 3rd, 4th, ... root and check if it is an integer.

Comment: Interesting. I always thought it would fail only even numbers. Do you have a more detailed reference?

Comment: @NiklasB. See edit with a bit more explanation how the method works.

Comment: Thanks! Good explanation :)

Comment: @ntysdd yes you are right, it is possible but less likely. I have updated the answer accordingly.